# Constrained Optimization with an External Parameter

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization

In theory, is it correct to pose a constrained optimization problem to minimize a nonlinear function of **two variables** with respect to **three parameters**, where the third parameter relates the two variables of the function?

For example, suppose we aim to minimize an objective function $\mathscr F(a,b)$, for the design parameters $a$, $b$, and $c$, such that $c=a^2+b^2$. Is this mathematically correct?

*Please have a detailed and proven statement if possible.

Thanks.*

Comment: Why no? What is the function?

Comment: wait, are a and b both design parameters to fix before solving and at the same time variables to optimize with respect to?

Comment: @mathreadler: yes.

Comment: i dont understand how that could work, but maybe i am being tired.

Comment: @mathreadler: Do you think it does not work?

Comment: You could have $c$ as a parameter to fix before trying to solve, then the $c=a^2+b^2$ becomes a constraint on $a$ and $b$ if they are variables you solve with respect to. But I don't think you could have $a,b$ as both design parameters and variables to optimize with respect to at the same time.

Comment: Crossposted on MO: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/282249/constrained-optimization.

Comment: @Alex M.: That's true. The thing is that I need more detailed explanations.

Comment: Nothing to prove or show, this is simply a special case of constrained optimization https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constrained_optimization

Comment: @AlexM.: How do you explain a result in which the constraint $c=a^2+b^2$ is not satisfied?  
Remember that $c$ is not a function variable.